# asp.net MVC 3 Razor layout error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my asp.net MVC 3 application, I have nested layouts. I have followed following link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/15/razor-nested-layouts-and-redefined-sections.aspx

My main layout page is_MasterLayout.cshtml and then a nested layout page _fullLayout.cshtml. In  _fullLayout.cshtml, I have:

```
@this.RedefineSection("BodyTitle")
@this.RedefineSection("Showcase")
```

but I am getting on these lines. Error is:

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'ASP._Page_Views_Shared__fullLayout_cshtml' does not contain a definition for 'RedefineSection' and the best extension method overload 'SectionExtensions.RedefineSection(System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase, string)' has some invalid arguments

Source Error:

Line 9:
Line 10: }
Line 11: @this.RedefineSection("BodyTitle")
Line 12: @this.RedefineSection("Showcase")
Line 13: @RenderBody()

my helper methods are defined like this:

```
public static class SectionExtensions
{

    private static readonly object _o = new object();

    public static HelperResult RenderSection(this WebPageBase page, string sectionName, Func<object, HelperResult> defaultContent)
    {
        if (page.IsSectionDefined(sectionName))
            return page.RenderSection(sectionName);
        else
            return defaultContent(_o);
    }

    public static HelperResult RedefineSection(this WebPageBase page, string sectionName)
    {
        return RedefineSection(page, sectionName, defaultContent: null);
    }

    public static HelperResult RedefineSection(this WebPageBase page, string sectionName, Func<object, HelperResult> defaultContent)
    {
        if (page.IsSectionDefined(sectionName))
            page.DefineSection(sectionName, () => page.Write(page.RenderSection(sectionName)));
        else if (defaultContent != null)
            page.DefineSection(sectionName, () => page.Write(defaultContent(_o)));
        return new HelperResult(_ => { });
    }

}
```

Please suggest solution.

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RedefineSection helper contains two or more argument

```
RedefineSection(this WebPageBase page, string sectionName)
```

but you are passing only one in your view

```
@this.RedefineSection("BodyTitle")
@this.RedefineSection("Showcase")
```

According to

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/15/razor-nested-layouts-and-redefined-sections.aspx

you have to put something

```
@this.RedefineSection("TitleSection",
                  @<h1>Default SubLayout title</h1>)
```

Comment: I used it like this: @this.RedefineSection("BodyTitle", @<h1>Default SubLayout title</h1>)
@this.RedefineSection("Showcase", @<h1>Default SubLayout showcase</h1>) but still same error

Comment: one this to mention, I didn't define this section in content page.

Comment: @RenderSection("TitleSection", required: false)
@RenderBody() in master layout

Answer (score 0):

Following step to resolve your issue
1. Get the namespace of your class "SectionExtensions". 
2. In your layout page where you use RedefineSection import that name space at top of page using

@using yournamespace;

Thanks.

Comment: the class is not under any namespace. I enclosed it with namespace and added "@using CreditRegistry.Models" at the top but still same error.

Comment: put namespace in both materpage. Master layout as well as nested.